# Converting datatable column to double C#

Tags: csv, datatable, double

I read some columns from a csv file and then display it in a DataGridView. The column "Value" contains some 3-digit integer values. I want to have this integer values shown in the datagridview as doubles with one decimals place. The conversion doesn't seem to work. Also when I load a large csv file (around 30k rows) it is loaded immediately but with conversion it takes too much time.

```
 using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {
                    CsvReader csvReadFile = new CsvReader(str);

                    dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(double));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Time Stamp", typeof(DateTime));

                    while (csvReadFile.Read()) {

                        var row = dt.NewRow();
                        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns) {
                            row[column.ColumnName] = csvReadFile.GetField(column.DataType, column.ColumnName);
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);

                        foreach (DataRow row1 in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            row1["Value"] = (Convert.ToDouble(row1["Value"])/10);
                        }
                    }
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have two questions:

1. How to format the value to a single decimal place of scale.
2. Why does the convert section of code take so long?

Here are possibilities

1. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176657/c-sharp-datatable-decimal-with-precision)  which specifies a possibility of using

`String.Format("{0:0.##}", (Decimal) myTable.Rows[rowIndex].Columns[columnIndex]);`

2. You are iterating over every row of the datatable **every time you read a line.** That means when you read line 10 of the CSV, you will iterate over rows 1-9 of the DataTable again!  And so on for each line you read!  Refactor to pull that loop out of the ReadLine... something like this:

   ```
   using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {
               CsvReader csvReadFile = new CsvReader(str);

               dt = new DataTable();
               dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(double));
               dt.Columns.Add("Time Stamp", typeof(DateTime));

               while (csvReadFile.Read()) {

                   var row = dt.NewRow();
                   foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns) {
                       row[column.ColumnName] = csvReadFile.GetField(column.DataType, column.ColumnName);
                   }
                   dt.Rows.Add(row);
               }
               foreach (DataRow row1 in dt.Rows)
               {
                   row1["Value"] = (Convert.ToDouble(row1["Value"])/10);
               }
           }
           dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
   ```